# How to returning mysql_fetch_array in function

Tags: php, mysql

I have some question about MySQL in PHP.

This is my config code:

```
<?php

class Core{

    public $connect;

public function __construct(){
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'fix';
    $this->connect = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$database);
    if(!$this->connect) echo mysql_error();
    }

    public function siteTitle(){
    $title = "title";
    $tagline = "tagline";
    return $title. " - ".$tagline;
    }

    public function load($file,$data){
        extract($data);
        require "$file.php";
    }

    public function searchResult(){
        $query = $this->connect->query("SELECT * FROM `location`");
        if($query->num_rows > 0){
            $columns = $query->fetch_assoc();
            return $columns;    
        }
    }



    public function locationStatus($id){
        $location = $this->searchResult();
        $locationId = $location['id'];
        if($locationId == 1){
            echo "Available <i class='ui icon circle green'></i>";
        }elseif($locationId == 2){
            echo "Under Counstruction <i class='ui icon circle orange'></i>";
        }else{
            echo "Unavailable <i class='ui icon circle red'></i>";
        }

    }


}


?>
```

I will display a result from searchResult() function in searchResult.php file:

```
      <div style='border:1px solid #ccc; padding:3px;'>
        <img src="asset/images/<?php echo "$data[image].jpg"; ?>" class='ui image medium' style='padding-right:10px;float:left' />
       <h2 style='font-family:nexa;color:rgb(36,162,217);line-height:0;'><?php echo $data['title']; ?></h2>
       <h4><span style='color:orange;'>Location Address: </span><?php echo $data['subtitle']; ?></h4>
       <p><?php echo $data['description']; ?></p>
       <br />
       <p>
       <i class='ui icon marker big orange'></i>Checkin: <?php echo $data['checkin']; ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='ui icon clock big orange'></i>Published at: <?php echo $data['published']; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Status: <?php echo $this->locationStatus($data['id']); ?>
       </p>
       <a style='' href='location/<?php echo $data['slug']; ?>' class='ui button blue'>READ MORE</a>

</div>
```

And the searchResult.php, i call it in Index.php with code:

```
<?php echo $this->load('templates/searchResult', $this->searchResult()); ?>
```

My question is:

Why the result from my sql query is not a looping? Although, I was looping it with a while loop?

Thanks. Sorry if my language is bad.

Comment: Check the method `searchResult()` **There is no while loop**

Comment: yeah, what `while` loop? probably the one for `$data`

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh sorry, before the code I share, the code is with while not if but it's not work a looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call your View like this

```
<?php 
    echo $this->load('templates/searchResult', $this->searchResult()); 
?>
```

You will have to put the loop in the `searchResult()` method, so that this one call will return all the rows.

```
public function searchResult(){
    $query = $this->connect->query("SELECT * FROM `location`");

    $rows = array();

    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        while ( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() ) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $rows;    
}
```

Then in your View, loop over `$data`

Comment: As an alternative to the `while`,  [fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) can be used with `resulttype` set as `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, like this: `$rows = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function searchResult(){
    $query = $this->connect->query("SELECT * FROM `location`");
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        while ($columns = $query->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $data[] = $columns;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

You need the while loop in the searchResult function.